# Meaning of "Guess what ? Corgi butt"

Tags: idiom-meaning, jokes

It seems the sentence "Guess what ? Corgi butt" is quite popular: a web search provides a wealth of stickers, mugs and T-shirts with the same exact wording (and many cute corgis in different positions).

I have some trouble to understand what is the point of this sentence. Is this a reference to something? What does it mean? In what context can it be used?

Unfortunately a search in the Urban Dictionnary didn't help, it seems there is no entry for it.

Comment: It’s a riff on “Guess what?  That’s what.” That was used to torment kids at least in the 60s and 70s and probably before.

Comment: Never heard of it.  You might look into "Guess what? Chicken butt."  That's a piece of nonsense that has been around for decades.